# Square root of a prime is irrational

Tags: elementary-number-theory, radicals, gcd-and-lcm, rationality-testing

How can one prove that the square root of a prime number (e.g. $ \sqrt 61$) is irrational.

First we need to prove that $61$ is prime. This can be done by simply showing that $$ 49 < 61 < 64$$ and so $$ 7 < \sqrt 61 < 8$$ then the only possible prime factors of $61$ are $2 , 3, 5, 7$. Then by contradictions and DIC we can show that $61$ is prime.

Now how can we show that $\sqrt 61$ is irrational?

Comment: If you want to do this for a prime number, do "the standard thing".  Let $p$ be prime, assume that $\sqrt{p} = \frac{a}{b}$ where $a,b$ are coprime.  Then, rewrite it as $a^2 = pb^2$, and derive a contradiction (an easy one - write out the prime factorization of both sides and count how many times $p$ occurs in both sides - the right side should have an odd number of $p$'s, the left side should have an even number).

Comment: What do mean by only  possible prime factors of 61 are 2,3,5,7 ?

Comment: @Fawad If 61 is composite, then its prime factors are less than or equal to $\sqrt61$ .

Comment: You don't mean that 2,3,5 and 7 are the only possible prime factors.  You mean one o 2,3,5 or 7 must be a prime factor.  If $p*q = x$ and $p, q$ are prime the *one* of them must be $\le \sqrt{x}$ and the *other* must be $\ge \sqrt{x}$.  And if we find the smaller one, then we can find the larger one by dividing be the smaller one. So we only have to *check* to the square root.  But that's not to find *all* prime factors; just to find *one*.  51 has 3 as a prime factor.  *AND* it has 51/3 = 17.  We only had to *check* to 7 but in doing so we *found* 17.

Comment: "If 61 is composite, then its prime factors are less than or equal to 6–√1"  Incorrect.  Then *some* of it's prime factors must be less than or equal to $\sqrt{61}$.  **AND** some of its  factors (maybe prime) must be GREATER than or equal to $\sqrt{61}$.  Example $55$ has a prime fact $5 < 7$.  AND it has another prime factor $11 > 7$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $61=a^2/b^2$, where $a$ and $b$ are both in lowest terms. Then $$
61 \cdot b^2 =a^2
$$ since $a^2$ is multiple of $61^2$, or not at all, this simply cannot happen in lhs --- it has odd number of factor of 61, if any.

Comment: OP means 61 , and 51 was a typo

Comment: "since a is multiple of $61^2$, or not at all, this simply cannot happen."  What does "or not at all" mean?  And why can that "simply not happen?  Why can't $a = 61^k$?  Your proof is not done yet.

Comment: Sorry, typo. I mean $a^2$ is multiple of $61^2$.